# How to concatenate 2 binary numbers?

Tags: java, binary, concatenation, bit

I have 2 integer values , x and y. x is 2 bits, and y is 10 bits . I need to find z , which is concatenation of x and y. z is 12 bits. How do I do that in java? I'd also appreciate if you could explain the logic behind that. 
Thanks.

Comment: it was not clear, but now I get it :) . Thanks

Comment: The 'accepted' answer on that other question is overly complicated.  No looping needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x` is to be the high-order part of the result:

`int z = (x << 10) | y;`

In other words, `y` is used directly as bits 0 to 9 of the result, and we shift `x` so that its value is in bits 10 and 11.  Then we combine those two.

(Bits numbered from 0 at the least significant end)